# kafka mongodb sink connector not starting

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've installed confluent_3.3.0 and started zookeper, schema-registry and kafka broker. I have also downloaded mongodb connector from [this link](https://github.com/RADAR-CNS/MongoDb-Sink-Connector).

**Description:** I'm running sink connector using the following command:

`./bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /home/username/mongo-connect-test/kafka-connect-mongodb/quickstart-couchbase-sink.properties`

**Problem:** I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:91)
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.NO_DEFAULT_VALUE from class org.radarcns.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector
```

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This connector is using, at its latest version, an old version of the kafka-clients API. Specifically, it is depending on a constructor of the class `org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig` that does not exist in Apache Kafka versions `>= 0.11.0.0`

Confluent Platform version `3.3.0` is using Apache Kafka `0.11.0.0`

To fix this issue, the recommended approach would be to update the connector code to use the most recent versions of Apache Kafka APIs.