# Kafka connect ftp

Tags: apache-kafka, ftp, apache-kafka-connect

While running the connectors for kafka-connect-ftp showing this below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:54)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:54)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:279)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:193)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:153)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:75)
```

i have referred two community website which is already given in confluent connector website
https://github.com/Eneco/kafka-connect-ftp
https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor

Anyone please suggest a solution for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with this connector:

1. It bundles, along with its dependencies, classes from Connect's API. That is, it bundles classes in the package `org.apache.kafka.connect`. This is not advised and such dependencies should be marked as provided.
2. The actual reason that the connector fails with class loading issues is that it is depending (at least according to its `master` branch) on a version of Apache Kafka that probably does not match the version of the deployed Connect worker. Specifically, it depends on `kafkaVersion = '0.10.2.0'` which is not the latest. Kafka Connect, in its recent versions that offer class loading isolation, will ignore what it considers system classes, such as classes in `org.apache.kafka.connect` when they are imported by connectors' jars. Instead, it will load such classes from the Kafka Connect jars that ship with Apache Kafka.

The above issues may cause class loading failures, as the ones you observe.

Ideally, they should be addressed at the connector level.

Workarounds you may apply are:

- build the connector code from source, after upgrading the Kafka version it depends upon. Also mark its Kafka dependencies as provided (including Kafka Connect and Kafka Clients dependencies). Or,
- downgrade your deployed Kafka Connect version to match exactly the version that the connector currently depends upon.

A similar issue has been recorded here:
[kafka mongodb sink connector not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175455/kafka-mongodb-sink-connector-not-starting/47191363#47191363)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response konstantine karantasis.

Comment: i have tried to change the version of connect-api based on my confluent kafka version. Now im not getting the implementing class error

Comment: I am getting different error now                                                                       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.eneco.trading.kafka.connect.ftp.source.FtpSourceConnector

Comment: This is because there is no class name like com.eneco.trading.kafka.connect.ftp.source.FtpSourceConnecto‌​r  in the kafka-connect-ftp jar , after i build a maven .

Comment: I changed `kafkaVersion = '1.0.0'` in `build.gradle` and built the connector with `./gradlew clean shadowJar`. Build was successful and connector passed its unit tests. I see the connector class in the uber jar under `./build/libs`. I didn't try to load the ftp connector. Notice that the project uses `gradle` not `maven`.

Comment: i am referring to 2nd community which i have mentioned the website link in above. I have updated my build.gradle file for kafkaversion. And i tried to build the connector with ./gradlew clean shadowJar . Build was failure . showing this below error.

Comment: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
No git repo found
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/usr/lib/confluent/stream-reactor-master/build.gradle' line: 51
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'stream-reactor-master'.
> Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 128

Comment: I have tried to clone that project and gradle build was successfull now . After this i have started to run the connectors for kafka-connect-ftp , i am getting this error now

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser.registerAppInfo(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/metrics/Metrics;)V
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectMetrics.<init>(ConnectMetrics.java:79)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:95)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:83)